# Swift 2.1 error "Binary operator || cannot be applied to two Bool operands"

Tags: swift, sorting

So aside from the confusing language (a logical operator doesn't work with two boolean operands, what?), this is frustrating because I got my code working in a Playground in my project, but when I copy the exact same function into a controller I get the referenced error.

In case there's a better way, my goal is to sort an array of objects.  The objects include a time component and I'd like to sort on that.  The time is stored as a string of the format "mm:ss" because these are not discrete events that occur on a given date-time, but rather recurring events that occur (for example) "every Tuesday from 17:45-18:30".

The code feels reasonably straightforward:

```
func sortStringAsTime(first:String, second:String){
     let firstSet = first.componentsSeparatedByString(":")
     let secondSet = second.componentsSeparatedByString(":")

     return firstSet[0] < secondSet[0] ||   // Sort by hour
            firstSet[0] == secondSet[0] &&  // hours are the same
            firstSet[1] < secondSet[1]      // sort by minutes
}
```

The error comes on the return statement. Again, works as expected in the Playground, but gives me the error when I copy/paste it into my controller code.

Comment: Did you try your statement with proper parentheses? Maybe Swift doesn't exactly know how to process it in your case.

Comment: Parentheses will not matter, the operations will be evaluated left-to-right which is as expected.  Also, the Playground evaluated it just fine as-is.

Comment: You forgot to add the return type `-> Bool` to the function :)

Comment: Thanks @MartinR, figured it out on my own (See my answer). That said, make your comment an answer and I'll give you credit for it.

Comment: No need for a duplicate answer :)

Answer (score 8):

Well, damnit.  So this is interesting.  I figured it out. The error given is crap and unhelpful, but the real problem was that my function didn't declare a return type.  Not sure why the Playground didn't complain, and I'm not sure how that error message was supposed to give me that insight.  I noticed it after I tried just returning `true` and continuing with having my other code call the sort so as to move things along.

Fixed it as follows:

```
func sortStringAsTime(first:String, second:String) -> Bool {
        let firstSet = first.componentsSeparatedByString(":")
        let secondSet = second.componentsSeparatedByString(":")

        return firstSet[0] < secondSet[0] || // Sort by hour
            firstSet[0] == secondSet[0] &&  // hours are the same
            firstSet[1] < secondSet[1]
    }
```

Comment: Yes, Swift compiler errors can be mysterious, but you did the right thing: *Simplify* the code until the problem becomes obvious.

Comment: Thanks, yeah.  Nothing like jumping into a new language to remind you of all the stuff you take for granted in a language you've been at for a while.  And remind you how to dig yourself back out again...

Comment: @Paul Yeah.  Now that Swift is open source, that should help a lot.